# Problems in P with provably faster randomized algorithms

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, randomized-algorithms

Are there any problems in $\mathsf{P}$ that have randomized algorithms beating lower bounds on deterministic algorithms? More concretely, do we know any $k$ for which $\mathsf{DTIME}(n^k) \subsetneq \mathsf{PTIME}(n^k)$? Here $\mathsf{PTIME}(f(n))$ means the set of languages decidable by a randomized TM with constant-bounded (one or two-sided) error in $f(n)$ steps.

> Does randomness buy us anything inside $\mathsf{P}$?

To be clear, I am looking for something where the difference is asymptotic (preferably polynomial, but I would settle for polylogarithmic), not just a constant.

*I am looking for algorithms asymptotically better in the worst case. Algorithms with better expected complexity are not what I am looking for. I mean randomized algorithms as in RP or BPP not ZPP.*

Comment: Maybe "Yao's technique" is what you are looking for. A brief description can be found at http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs2150/yao/yao.html

Comment: @WuYin if I understand correctly that goes in the direction of lower-bounding randomized algorithms by the average case behavior of deterministic algorithm.. I will look more into it, but the way I see it, this could only ever lead to proving that randomness does *not* buy us anything inside $P$.. Am I correct?

Comment: For finding any element in sequence of length $n$ with rank in [$\frac{n}{4}$,$\frac{3*n}{4}$] we can simply return any random element and it will be correct with $\frac{1}{2}$ probability hence its O(1)! Whereas a Deterministic algorithm would at least examine some fraction of the input and hence $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: @rizwanhudda There might be some problems with that. First, I am looking for a decision problem. Second, in the Turing model, returning a random element is $\Omega (n)$, since there is no random access. Maybe, the machine always outputs the first element? Still, the first problem is bigger.

Comment: Do you mean las vegas or monte carlo style random algorithms?

Comment: @Joe Monte Carlo

Comment: The last paragraph does not make sense because every Las Vegas algorithm can be converted to a Monte Carlo algorithm.

Comment: afaik this is essentially/ formally equivalent to the open [P=?BPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_%28complexity%29) question, ie active area of research. see also recent cstheory question [when does randomization speed up algorithms and it "shouldnt"](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31195/when-does-randomization-speed-up-algorithms-and-it-shouldnt). also is that a std defn of PTIME used elsewhere or not?

Comment: @vzn No it isn't. Even if P=BPP, it could be that randomization helps, but only polynomially.

Comment: Related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31195/when-does-randomization-speed-up-algorithms-and-it-shouldnt.

Answer (score 17):

***Polynomial identity testing*** admits a randomised polynomial time algorithm (see the
[Schwartz-Zippel lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma)), and we currently don't have a deterministic 
polynomial time or even a sub-exponential time algorithm for it.

***Game tree evaluation*** Consider a complete binary tree with $n$ leaf nodes each
storing a 0/1 value. The internal nodes contain OR/AND gates in alternate levels.
It can be proved using adversary argument that every deterministic algorithm
would have to examine $\Omega{(n)}$ leaf nodes in the worst case. However there is
a simple randomised algorithm which takes has *expected* running time of $O(n^{0.793})$ 
Look at [slides](http://theory.stanford.edu/~pragh/amstalk.pdf) 14-27 of the talk.

***Oblivious routing on a hypercube*** Consider a cube in $n$-dimensions containing
$N=2^n$ vertices. Each vertex has a packet of data and a destination that it
wants to eventually deliver the packet to. The destination of all the packets
are different. Even for this, It has been proved that any deterministic routing strategy would take $\Omega{\big(\sqrt{\frac{N}{n}}\big)}$ steps. However, there is a simple
randomised strategy which will finish in *expected* $O(n)$ steps *with high probability*.

Note that in randomised algorithms, the expected cost $E(F(n))$ *with high probability* (like for eg. $Pr[F(n) > 10 \cdot E(F(n))] < \frac{1}{n^2}$) is
equivalent to worst case in practice.

Comment: Also, consider testing for matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ if $A B = C$. We currently know no $o(2^{2.3})$ algorithm, we know a randomized $O(n^2)$ algorithm. The point is, are there problems for which we can **prove** that randomized algorithms are better?

Comment: @aelguindy I get your point. But, for PIT the best known determinstic algorithm is exponential. And, derandomizing PIT is an important open problem in Theoretical CS.

Comment: I have added Game tree evaluation and hypercube routing to the post, for which randomised algorithms do provably better than determinstic counterparts.

Comment: OK, for the Game Tree evaluation, if I understand correctly, it runs in expected $O(n^{0.793})$, right? I mean there are cases where it will run in $\Omega(n)$. Is it the case with the third example too? I am not allowing for better expected time, I am looking for better worst-case complexity, allowed error in the output.

Comment: For Game tree evaluation I have not worked out to see if its expected $O(n^{0.793})$ *with high probability* or not. For oblivious routing I know that the result is expected O(n) *with high probability*. *Almost all* of the results for randomised algorithms have very less probability of deviation from expected value. That is why they work so well in practice.

Comment: So they are not better in worst case. As much as I appreciate the examples, I'm afraid that is not exactly what I am looking for. The examples were very enlightening though!

Comment: @aelguindy I think for Las vegas algorithms the worst case lower bounds on deterministic algorithms still apply, since Randomised Algorithms are essentially defined by a distribution over Deterministic Algorithms.

Comment: @aelguindy I shall look for such a monte-carlo algorithm. Should I add a note at the beginning of my answer stating that it doesn't answer the exact question?

Comment: Yes, please do :-).

Answer (score 5):

Investigating the worst-case is meaningless for randomised algorithms. Not only will the worst-case runtime often be infinite but also they *can not* outperform deterministic algorithms in that metric.

Consider any randomised algorithm $A$. Obtain a deterministic algorithm $B$ by fixing the random tape for $A$ to $0^\infty$. Then, $T_B(n) \leq T_A(n)$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 5):

There are many problems where we know of an efficient randomized algorithm, and we don't know of any deterministic algorithm that we can prove is efficient.  However, this may reflect shortcomings in our ability to prove things about complexity rather than any fundamental difference.

Based on [your comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/problems-in-p-with-provably-faster-randomized-algorithms#comment6364_2365), it appears you meant to ask whether there exists any problem where there is an efficient randomized algorithm, and we can *prove* there is no deterministic algorithm of comparable efficiency.  I don't know of any such problem.

Indeed, there are reasonable grounds to suspect that such problems might be unlikely to exist.  Heuristically, the existence of such a problem would likely mean that secure cryptography is impossible.  That seems like a rather implausible outcome.

What's the connection, you ask?  Well, consider any randomized algorithm $A$ that solves some problem efficiently.  It relies upon random coins: random bits obtained from a true-random source.  Now suppose we take a cryptographic-quality pseudorandom generator, and replace the true-random source with the output of the pseudorandom generator.  Call the resulting algorithm $A'$.  Note that $A'$ is a deterministic algorithm and its running time is approximately the same as $A$.

Also, if the cryptographic PRNG is secure, heuristically we should expect $A'$ to be a good algorithm if $A$ is:

- For instance, if $A$ is a Las Vegas algorithm (it always outputs the correct answer, and terminates rapidly with high probability), then $A'$ will be a pretty good deterministic algorithm (always outputs the correct answer, and terminates rapidly for most inputs).
- As another example, if $A'$ is a Monte Carlo algorithm (deterministic running time, and outputs the correct answer with probability at least $1-\varepsilon$), then $A$ will be a pretty good deterministic algorithm (deterministic running time, and outputs the correct answer on a fraction $1-\varepsilon$ of all inputs).

Therefore, if the cryptographic PRNG is secure and there is an efficient randomized algorithm, you get a deterministic algorithm that is pretty good.  Now there are many constructions of cryptographic PRNGs that are guaranteed to be secure if certain cryptographic assumptions hold.  In practice, those cryptographic assumptions are widely believed: at least, secure commerce and transactions rely upon them being true, so we're apparently willing to bet large sums of money that secure cryptography exists.  The only way this transformation can fail is if cryptographic PRNG don't exist, which in turn implies secure cryptography is impossible.  While we don't have any proof that this isn't the case, it seems like an unlikely outcome.

Details of the construction: Here's how $A'$ works.  On input $x$, it derives a seed for the cryptographic PRNG as a function of $x$ (e.g., by hashing $x$), and then simulates $A(x)$, using the output of the cryptographic PRNG as the coins for $A$.  For instance, a specific instantiation would be to set $k=\text{SHA256}(x)$, then use $k$ as the seed for AES256 in counter mode, or some other cryptographic PRNG.  We can prove the above statements under the random oracle model.

If you're unhappy with the idea that $A'$ might output incorrect results on some small fraction of inputs, that can be addressed.  If you repeat $A'$ multiple times and take a majority vote, the error probability decreases exponentially fast in the number of iterations.  So, by iterating a constant number of times, you can get the error probability $\varepsilon$ to be below $1/2^{256}$, which means the chances that you run across an input $x$ where the algorithm outputs the wrong answer are vanishingly small (less than the chances of getting struck by lightning multiple times in a row).  Moreover, with the construction I gave above, the chances that an adversary can even *find* an input $x$ where $A'$ gives the wrong answer can be made very small, as that would require breaking the security of the SHA256 hash.  (Technically, this requires the random oracle model to justify, so it means that $A$ must be chosen to be "independent" of SHA256 and not hardcode in it calculations that are related to SHA256, but almost all real-world algorithms will satisfy that requirement.)

If you want a stronger theoretical basis, you can iterate $A$ $\Theta(n)$ times, and get the error probability to be below $1/2^n$, where $n$ is the length of the input $x$.  Now the fraction of $n$-bit inputs where $A'$ gives an incorrect answer is strictly less than $1/2^n$.  But there are only $2^n$ possible $n$-bit inputs, and on each one $A$ is either correct or incorrect, so it follows that there is no input where $A'$ is incorrect: $A'$ is correct on all inputs, and this holds unconditionally.  If $A$ runs in time $t(n)$, then $A'$ runs in time $\Theta(n \cdot t(n))$, so $A'$ is a bit slower than $A$ but not too much slower.  This is the content of Adleman's proof that BPP is contained in P/poly.  For practical purposes this is probably overkill, but if you like clean proofs that avoid cryptographic assumptions or if you approach this from a theoretician's perspective then you might like this version better.

For more details on the latter theoretical considerations and additional problems where we know of an efficient randomized algorithm but we don't know of any deterministic algorithm that we can prove is efficient, see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31195/5038

In summary: For any problem where we know an efficient randomized algorithm, we also know of a deterministic algorithm that seems likely to be efficient in practice -- but at present we don't know how to *prove* that it is efficient.  One possible interpretation is that we're just not very good at proving stuff about algorithms.